# SQS Triggered lambda not working with batches

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have lambda with a SQS trigger with

- batch size 10
- batch window 60 secs
- Lambda timeout 5 mins
- Visibility Timeout 6 mins
- zero lambda retries

After triggering 30 messages in the queue, all the message are becoming inflight and the lambda process 15 to 16 messages and once the visibility time is left over the messages are going to DLQ.

Tried with 100 and 1 batch size, it stops unexpectedly after processing some messages and drop rest to DLQ.

Not able to understand why it stop processing after certain time.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you check your lambda logs? Maybe it errors out while processing the msgs?

Comment: I don't see any errors in Lambda logs as well

Comment: if any message in the batch fails the batch  should go  to DLQ, and should pick another batch , The problem is it stop processing after certain message.

Comment: Lambda does not "stop" by itself. Probably there are no more messages in the sqs left for processing as all of them failed.

Comment: You need to read [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) carefully and implement its suggestions for redrive policy, visibility timeout of 6x function timeout plus the value of MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds etc.

Comment: Does your Lambda function code correctly look through the `event['Records']` array? A common error is to only process `event['Records'][0]`. Messages should only go to the Dead Letter Queue if they failed to process.

Comment: Yesfor record in event['Records']:
        payload = record['body']
        messageid = record['messageId']
        receiptHandle = record['receiptHandle']
        attributes = record['attributes']

Comment: Also I am seeing errors in Lambda Cloud watch metrics, looks like after a while lambda doesn't process the message and fails and I don't see the errors in logs only in metrics